# Connecting points on graph via dotted lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

How could I connect these points with dotted, vertical lines?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center]
\addplot [only marks] table{
0 0.00390625
1 0.05078125
2 0.26171875
3 0.68359375
4 1
};
\addplot [domain=0:1] {0.00390625};
\addplot [domain=1:2] {0.05078125};
\addplot [domain=2:3] {0.26171875};
\addplot [domain=3:4] {0.68359375};
\addplot [domain=4:5] {1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center]
\addplot [only marks] table{
0 0.00390625
1 0.05078125
2 0.26171875
3 0.68359375
4 1
};
\addplot [domain=0:1] {0.00390625}coordinate[pos=1](b);
\addplot [domain=1:2] {0.05078125}coordinate[pos=0](c)coordinate[pos=1](d);
\addplot [domain=2:3] {0.26171875}coordinate[pos=0](e)coordinate[pos=1](f);
\addplot [domain=3:4] {0.68359375}coordinate[pos=0](g)coordinate[pos=1](h);
\addplot [domain=4:5] {1}coordinate[pos=0](i);
\draw[thick,dotted,red] (b) -- (c)(d) -- (e) (f) -- (g) (h) -- (i);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have defined the coordinates along with the graph and then it becomes a formal affair to draw the lines.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Thanks! How did you insert the preview of that code?

Comment: Never mind. I see now that I can view the source of your comment by clicking edit.

Comment: @jodawill Press `Ctrl+G` and upload the png figure.